# Elasticsearch, counting not included terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get a single, or a couple, of ES requests to count the terms I have not included in my current search.

Let me elaborate.... My front-end looks like this:

[image: front-end]

I have Closed currently selected, so the other items should show how many items they would add if I were to include that term.

Assume that closed == 500 and Rejected == 100;
While I have closed selected the rejected field should have the number 100 appended to it. If I deselect closed , it should show the number 500. If I select rejected and *not* select closed it should also show 500.

Easy enough huh? We just add a bucket counting the status field and that will return a bucket for each of these items, we then get the value from it and display it.

That part I got :) However.... when I actually add a term (for example one that filters on NoOffer) the buckets won't include the others field...

This is what my query looks like (global buckets by: [ChintanShah25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3601682/chintanshah25))

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "from": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "createdAt": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "fromPlace": "*rotter*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "status": "closed"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "status": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "all_status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.raw",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The global now shows all the different status codes, but it doesn't take into regard the rest of the statement. The "fromPlace" filter doesn't get applied.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your current query will give you only "closed" count but you want all counts, right?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [global aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) which will include all the fields regardless of the query. You could also use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) for selective stats if you want.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "status": {
        "value": "closed"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "everything": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "all_status": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status.raw",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is sort-off what I want. It shows all status fields as a bucket but it doesn't update the value according to the query. As mentioned in my original post I'd like the values to represent the current state. If I have added a couple of filters the numbers should still reflect how many rows they'd add. Say that I also filter on "fromPlace", the numbers should be calculated *after* the filter has applied. See me edit in a few mins for a new query.